# Difference Between Umbraco and Vanila Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

What is the difference between umbraco and vanila umbraco.
i'm currently using umbraco 6.2.1 version in my website.
Any special procedure available for upgrading this version to Vanila umbraco version.

Comment: Do you have a link to this "Vanila umbraco"? Never heard of it.

Comment: i seen this in [umbraco forum](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-pro/contour/68168-vanilla-727-install-and-form-not-installing)

Answer (score 14):

Vanilla Umbraco means a fresh clean installation of Umbraco, without any customization.

Vanilla is a general term used for software, see also on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software)

Related to upgrading, one approach is to do a new installation of Umbraco (we can called it a vanilla installation) and then deploy your code, and migrate the content. Instead of the [General Umbraco upgrade instructions](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/upgrading/general).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that there is no *running website* with a vanilla Umbraco install.  Umbraco is not a typical CMS.  You are customizing it as soon as you start setting up your site in it.  This is partly due to a choice on the Umbraco HQ team's decision to store their settings in the same files where you change settings by using Umbraco, requiring you to *merge* certain files during the upgrade.

As for upgrading, I'll warn you, there are a few ways to install Umbraco (Web PI, Nuget, Zip file), and if you upgrade in a way different than you installed, it can be hell.  Step one, back up your site (front-end file-system files and db)!  If you did not install Umbraco via Nuget (in Visual Studio), do not upgrade via Nuget.  You will regret it.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco upgrades are a problem.

If the versions are minor running the update-package umbracocms nuget might work, but it often leaves the project mismatching version assemblies elsewhere.

Upgrading Umbraco is a bit of a minefield. Soz

Comment: kinda scary... Just put embraco on two of my sites hosted by Arvixe and did so with Arvixe's script on their web hosting options.  Now i would like to update their default version to the most current version and was going to do it via VS via nuget.  

Hmmmmmm

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco is now at version 11 and have moved their code base from the .NET framework into .NET core. Newer version is offering so much more, block-list, block-grid, inline editing, so many new and improved property editors. Editing experience and working with the CMS has changed so much since version 6.

Vanilla Umbraco would a term for a non-configured, fresh install.

You can find out everything you need to know about Umbraco on their documentation pages.

https://docs.umbraco.com/getting-started

Umbraco is a free open source project so there is no cost if you want to roll your sleeves, dig in and move over to the newest version. There are some paid offerings as well that would give support if you needed it.

Now that they have moved away from the .NET framework and moved their code base over to .NET Core there is no longer a direct path to upgrade from version 8 and earlier to the most recent version 11.

I would recommend you set up a fresh install, configure and customize as desired and then move any relevant content over to your new site.

There are many articles out there detailing how others moved over to the newer version.

Good article here on how they upgraded from version 7 to the newer version 11.

https://skrift.io/issues/how-i-upgraded-my-umbraco-v7-project-to-umbraco-v11/

Worth the read if your planning on going down that path.

Good luck.